# Confused by the running time for finding the sum of even fibonacci numbers

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

I have two solutions for Project Euler question 2, namely find the sum of all even Fibonacci numbers less than 4 million.

Solution one (which takes an average of 11,000 nanoSeconds):

```
public class Solution {

static long startTime = System.nanoTime();
static final double UPPER_BOUND = 40e5;
static int sum = 2;

public static int generateFibNumber(int number1, int number2){
    int fibNum = number1+ number2;
    return fibNum;
}

public static void main( String args[] ) {
    int i = 2;
    int prevNum = 1;
    while(i <= UPPER_BOUND) {
        int fibNum = generateFibNumber(prevNum,i);
        prevNum = i;
        i = fibNum;
        if (fibNum%2 == 0){
            sum += fibNum;
        }
    }
    long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
    long time = stopTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Time: "+ time);
}
```

and solution two(which takes an average of 14,000 nanoseconds):

```
public class Solution2 {
static long startTime = System.nanoTime();  
final static int UPPER_BOUND = 4_000_000;
static int penultimateTerm = 2;                                         
static int prevTerm = 8;                                                
static int currentTerm = 34;                                             
static int sum = penultimateTerm+ prevTerm;                 

public static void main( String args[]) {
    while (currentTerm <= UPPER_BOUND) {
        sum+= currentTerm;
        penultimateTerm = prevTerm;
        prevTerm = currentTerm;
        currentTerm = (4*prevTerm) + penultimateTerm;
    }

    long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
    long time = stopTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Time: " + time);

}
```

Why is solution two taking longer when I am performing way fewer iterations inside the while loop and and also do not have an if statement?
Can this be done more efficiently?

Comment: Your timing code is inaccurate; you should start the timer in the main method, just before entering the while loop, not as a field initializer.

Comment: That was it. I am get 3400 nanoseconds for the first one and 3000 for the second. Which is what i was expecting( second one is faster)

Comment: Its worth nothing that you are not performing enough iterations to warm up the JVM.  This means you are working with the vagaries of how the interpreter behaves.  Note: You can cut the number iteration by uses every third Fibonacci number which is even (this cuts the number of iterations by a factor of three)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running your algorithm only once is a highly unreliable way of evaluating its performance, particularly when the times are on the order of 10ns. Your second method is, indeed, faster. I rewrote your code to iterate each algorithm 100 times and got quite different results from you.

Code:

```
public class Fib {
    private static int UPPER_BOUND = 4000000;
    private static int ITERS = 100;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long time1, time2;
        int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int iter = 0; iter < ITERS; ++iter) {
            sum1 = sol1();
        }
        time1 = System.nanoTime() - startTime;

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int iter = 0; iter < ITERS; ++iter) {
            sum2 = sol2();
        }
        time2 = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.println("Time1 = " + time1 + "; sum1 = " + sum1);
        System.out.println("Time2 = " + time2 + "; sum2 = " + sum2);
    }

    private static int sol1() {
        int sum = 2;
        int i = 2;
        int prevNum = 1;
        while(i <= UPPER_BOUND) {
            int fibNum = generateFibNumber(prevNum,i);
            prevNum = i;
            i = fibNum;
            if (fibNum%2 == 0){
                sum += fibNum;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static int sol2() {
        int penultimateTerm = 2;
        int prevTerm = 8;
        int currentTerm = 34;
        int sum = penultimateTerm + prevTerm;
        while (currentTerm <= UPPER_BOUND) {
            sum += currentTerm;
            penultimateTerm = prevTerm;
            prevTerm = currentTerm;
            currentTerm = (prevTerm << 2) + penultimateTerm;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static int generateFibNumber(int number1, int number2) {
        return number1+ number2;
    }
}
```

Results (typical):

> Time1 = 189910; sum1 = 4613732
>   Time2 = 35501; sum2 = 4613732

Note that in the second algorithm, I changed `(4*prevTerm)` with `(prevTerm << 2)`, which is slightly faster. This improved the time by about 5%. There's still a lot of overhead in each test: a function call and assigning the result to a local variable. However, by iterating you aren't down in the noise in your calls to `System.nanoTime()`.

Note that your first code was also using a `double` for `UPPER_BOUND`, which slows it down a bit. My code tried to make the tests as parallel as possible.

Comment: I should probably write a bash script to run my code of couple of 1000 times. Is there a more reliable way to look at/graph algorithm run times?

Comment: @yudhishthirsingh - I wouldn't use a bash script. That adds to the overhead because you need to load and initiate the program each time. The more overhead, the more the distinction is blurred between the things you are trying to measure. The best approach is to isolate what you want to measure as much as possible and then wrap the timing code as tightly as possible around it.

Answer (score 4):

The second version *is* faster. As pointed out in the comments you are timing inaccurately. Also timing a function that takes few microseconds is unreliable. You should run the code in a loop and calcaulte the total time for x iterations, then use that to calculate the average time per iteration.

Also I thought it might be useful to show why the code works. Note that the even numbers occur at every third index.

```
1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34
      ^        ^        ^
```

The second version is directly calculating the even numbers only. It does this by calculating the value of F(n+3) from F(n) and F(n-3).

```
F(n + 3) = F(n + 2) + F(n + 1)
         = F(n + 1) + F(n) + F(n + 1)                              [1]
         = F(n) + F(n - 1) + F(n) + F(n) + F(n - 1)                [2]
         = F(n) + F(n - 2) + F(n - 3) + F(n) + F(n) + F(n - 1)     [3]
         = F(n) + F(n) + F(n - 3) + F(n) + F(n)                    [4]
         = 4 * F(n) + F(n - 3)
```

The following identities are used:

1. `F(n + 2) = F(n + 1) + F(n)`
2. `F(n + 1) = F(n) + F(n - 1)`
3. `F(n - 1) = F(n - 2) + F(n - 3)`
4. `F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2)`

Comment: The question wasn't why the second solution works. It's why it is taking longer to execute.

Comment: @TedHopp: Ohh, I misread the question... However I guess the answer still might be useful for some people.

Comment: It is indeed a nice derivation.